# Check a process is still executing or terminated in windows

Tags: windows, process

I have one doubt as below:

I created one app which spawns one process (which does some work and terminates) internally using CreateProcess() windows API, now after sometime I want to check whether the process spawned is terminated or still executing, How can I check ?

I am using WaitForSingleObject(handle, timeinterval) API which I understand waits for that process to terminate till input timeinterval expires. Now when I check exit error code after this using API GetExitCodeProcess(), I get 259 as error code which means "STILL ACTIVE". What I understand is that sometimes the spawned process takes more time then timeinterval to execute because of some performance issues sometimes so it gets terminated with error code 259. Now how can I make sure that the spawned process executes properly in case if it needs more time before getting killed when timeinterval expires.

Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect anywhere. I am little new to windows platform.

Comment: for check are process terminated - use any wait function. `WaitForSingleObject` for example. when process is terminated - it go to signaled state

Comment: @RbMm I am little new to windows platform, Can you explain me what you meant by "when process is terminated - it go to signaled state" ? What is this signal state here ? Also i am already using this function but with a timeinterval so even if process is still not completed it will get terminated after that timeinterval i think, which is happening right now.

Comment: the process object internal have event (`DISPATCHER_HEADER` if be exactly) which set to signaled state when process terminated. as result any wait function show this

Comment: from `WaitForSingleObject` for example - `Waits until the specified object is in the signaled state or the time-out interval elapses.` - in case process (specified object) it go to signaled state just after process terminated

Comment: WaitForSingleObject does not terminate the process if the wait times out.  Nor does `STILL_ACTIVE` mean that the process has been terminated; typically, it means the process is still running.  If WaitForSingleObject returned `WAIT_OBJECT_0` then the process has exited and you can call GetExitCodeProcess; if it returned `WAIT_TIMEOUT` then the process is still running and you should not call GetExitCodeProcess.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @HarryJohnston

Comment: Thanks for explanation @RbMm